# Generalizing the construction of $PA^\omega$

Tags: logic, nonstandard-models

I'm taking an extremely basic course in mathematical logic where we briefly talked about nonstandard models of arithmetic. The only example we worked through has been the construction of $PA^\omega$ through the compactness theorem. EDIT: The axioms of $PA^\omega$ consist of the axioms of $PA$ along an infinite set of axioms of the form $\omega > n$ for each standard natural number $n$ (the notation is kind of unfortunate, perhaps I should have chosen a better name than $\omega$ for this symbol...).

I was wondering can this process of "extending" $PA$ to $PA^\omega$ be generalized?

I thought of defining something like $(PA^\omega)^{\omega'}$ adding more axioms of the form $\omega ' > n$ for $n$ *in* $PA^\omega$ but I'm not even sure this "*in*" would be well-defined. Is there a way to define such a model?

Comment: Please define what precisely you mean by $PA^\omega$, it is not notation I immediately recognize.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I added more details. Is there a more commonly accepted name for this model?

Comment: @Ettore You seem to be confused about the distinction between models and theories. $\text{PA}^\omega$ is a *theory*, which has many models. Similarly, you ask "is there a way to define such a model", but it looks like you're trying to describe a *theory*.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think you're right regarding both my confusion and my question, the part I'm interested in is actually the construction of such a theory. I don't know if this question is salvageable then, I'll think more about it...